# Error Checking In C

Tags: c, error-handling

I'm not as advance in C as yet so I'd need help with few problems. 1. Let's say I want to enter  character (y or n) and I don't want anything else other than that character, so I'll use a while loop to until its entered. I can't get it working, here's my code. It compiles and run but it won't carry out what I want, if I enter y it continues to loop likewise n

```
printf("Enter code(y/n): \n");
scanf(" %c", &code);
while (code != 'y' || 'n' ){
    printf("Try Again: \n");
    scanf(" %c", &code);
}
```

Comment: the while condition says not equal y or not =n .  it could be =y and so would not =n, so the loop continues.  and you probably want to allow capital y and capital n as valid inputs.

Comment: the returned value from scanf() and family, needs to be checked to assure the input/conversion operation was successful.

Comment: to avoid having two scanf statements for a single input, either change the while code block to a do...while code block or remove the first scanf statement and pre-initialize the code variable to something other than y or n.

Answer (score 1):

REPLACE

`while (code != 'y' || 'n' ){`         <-- condition evaluates always to TRUE

WITH

`while ((code != 'y' )&&(code != 'n')){`

Answer (score 1):

The line you have

```
while (code != 'y' || 'n' ){
```

is equivalent to:

```
while ((code != 'y') || 'n' ){
```

which evaluates to true all the time.

The logic you need is:

```
while (code != 'y' && code != 'n' ){
```

Comment: How can I use a loop to ensure that the user enters only a single character?

Comment: You can read an entire line using `fgets`. Then you can inspect an entire line one character at a time. Using `scanf` is not a good strategy for such checks.